# Change cell bind value and update Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to change the value of particular row's cell bind value. I've bind value with Name and Code property. Let suppose, first row selected. On CurruntCellChange Event, i want to change value of Name property to "1" in that particular row. i've write code to change as `((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Name = "1";` but changes not reflect.

```
<DataGrid  DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                   SelectionMode="Single" Name="Datagrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   PreviewKeyDown="Datagrid_PreviewKeyDown" 
                   CurrentCellChanged="Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged" SelectionChanged="Datagrid_SelectionChanged" SelectedCellsChanged="Datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Event:

```
private void Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Datagrid.BeginEdit();
            if (Datagrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGridCellInfo cell = Datagrid.SelectedCells[0];

                var generator = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
                int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
                int rowIndex = generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item));
 ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Name = "1";
}
```

Name Property:

```
namespace Inventory_Control.Classes
{
    class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string SubTotal { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us code for your Name property ?

Comment: ok please wait a minute

Comment: @Muds please check updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your `Item` class
and then in your

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

while you set, you need to raise 'Property Changed' event

To you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you need to implement this interface in you class, following is the simplest implementation for it

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and then your `Name` Property looks like

```
private string name;

public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do read about who UI gets updated in WPF, notifyproperty change is basis of notification in binding world. do read about it and dependency properties and behaviors too